# How to install boost on Linux with custom location of gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, boost, build, installation

My gcc compiler is at a custom location /my/path/hpgcc

I've downloaded the boost sources. Executed bootstrap.sh, but it fails because it runs with the default gcc.

Looking into it, I see that it fails at the first thing it does: building the Boost.Build engine:

```
gcc -o bootstrap/jam0 command.c compile.c debug.c expand.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c newstr.c option.c output.c parse.c pathunix.c pathvms.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c pwd.c class.c native.c md5.c w32_getreg.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c execunix.c fileunix.c
```

(fails because executed with the default gcc, and not my gcc version).

I've tried to change the gcc path in the user-config.jam file, but it doesn't help.  Probably because the Boost.Build's build script boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2/engine/build.sh doesn't use user-config.jam, and just uses the default locations.

Any solution?

Comment: Does this actually fail to produce a working bjam? You can build boost.build with a different toolset from the toolset that you use to compile boost.

Comment: As a hack, you could modify your `$PATH`, or edit `boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2/engine/build.sh`.

Comment: Mankarse: How can I build boost.build with my compiler?

Comment: Why do you want to use your special compiler to build boost.build?

Comment: Mankrase: As you suggested, I edited  boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2/engine/build.sh and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the line:

```
using gcc : : /my/path/hpgcc ;
```

to `user-config.jam`. `user-config.jam` will usually be in `/path/to/boost/tools/build/v2/`, but you can put a custom `user-config.jam` or `site-config.jam` in any of the places listed [here](https://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html).

`/my/path/hpgcc` should be the full path to the g++ executable.

---

EDIT (Igor Oks) : What eventually solved the problem is that I edited boost_1_47_0/tools/build/v2/engine/build.sh to make it use my custom gcc.

Answer (score 0):

We do this in our build environment by simply defining the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables to pickup our desired GCC first.